# PHP for loop not working with jQuery API (Uncaught TypeError)

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have this array full of YouTube Video ID's that I'm trying to load with jQuery. But for some reason it's not fully working, It's giving me this error in the console:

[image]

**CODE:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php
        $videos = array("VGh5DV0D3wk", "6y_NJg-xoeE", "9Q31J3mkCKY");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($videos); $i++) {
    ?>
        // -----------
        $.get(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
             part: 'snippet',
             key: 'AIzaSyDYwPzLevXauI-kTSVXTLroLyHEONuF9Rw',
                id: '<?php echo $videos[$i]; ?>',
          },
          function(data) {
             $('#playlist-item-<?php echo $i; ?>').text(data.items[<?php echo $i; ?>].snippet.title);
          });
    <?php
    }
    ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: please console log `data` and post it here

Comment: PHP only generates the JavaScript; thus PHP has *nothing* to do with the error, except as it incorrectly generates the content. Look at (and post, as text) the relevant *actual* generated content in such question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the response is having only one item. You don't have to increment the array index.

Use the below code.

```
$('#playlist-item-<?php echo $i; ?>').text(data.items[0].snippet.title);
```